# What else can I use instead of elif, if , else statements in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements, voice-recognition

Hello everyone ı wonder what else we can use instead of elif, if , else statements? or how can ı change given if , elif , else statement to any other method..

Assume that ı have voice assistant like this;

```
webb = ["open web browser","web browser", "open browser"]
thkns = ["thank you","thank you so much", "thanks"]
fav_web = ["open my favourite web site","favourite web site","my best web site"]
hwaru = ["how are you", "what's up", "how is going"]
thtime = ["whats the time" , "the time", "time"]

def assistant(command):
    if command in webb:
        talkMe("Opening your web browser")
        webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com.tr")

    elif command in thkns: 
        talkMe("You are welcome")


    elif command in fav_web:
        talkMe("Opening your site")
        webbrowser.open("www.stackoverflow.com")

    elif command in hwaru: 
        msg = ["ı am good, you?", "good", "not bad"]
        talkMe(random.choice(msg))


    elif command in thtime:
        strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        talkMe(f"The time is {strTime} ")
```

so I wonder, What else do I try instead of elif? Can you please explain to me? ı know elif , if , and else statements.In this case if I want to write other command ı have to write;

```
elif command in "":
    talkMe("")
    do some """

elif command in "": 
    """"
```

and so on.. so that rows are too many can ı make the codes more shorter instead of elif statements? 
or should i continue like this?

Comment: Less lines is not always "better". Also, remember that elifs get checked in order. | If you'd like something like `switch` statements in other languages, dictionaries are pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: The actions taken for each conditions are significantly different that it's hard to use a fundamentally different structure…

Comment: Thanks for the comments what about classes?

Comment: Consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dictionary. Here is complete example

```
def switch_demo(argument):
    switcher = {
        "open web browser": "Opening your web browser",
        "web browser": "Opening your web browser",
        "open browser": "Opening your web browser",
        "thank you": "You are welcome",
        "thank you so much": "You are welcome",
        "thanks": "You are welcome"
    }
    print(switcher.get(argument, "Invalid Command"))

command = "thank you"
switch_demo(command)
```

Comment: Hello my friend thx for the example but when ı run my program;

`I'm ready for next command`
 `Detected: thank you so much`
`You are welcome`
 `welcome`
`None`
`I'm ready for next command`

it return 2 times or 3 times but why ? :/

in my while loop ;
`switch_demo(command)`

Comment: What are you sending in the command? Or can you send your full example?

Comment: same , command = "thank you". 
And when ı said only "thank you", it's prints out and talk;

    You are welcome 
    welcome
 and prints out None

Okey let me send full example...

You can reach full example from here [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/q4Kg74w2WC/)

Comment: You must have something else in the code with the code above I get printed once You are welcome and that's it. Try to execute just the code above..

Comment: ı will try , thank you.. btw did you check my full example?

Comment: The issue is that in your switch case you use talkMe("You are welcome") and talkMe("welcome") .. you should get the result talkMeStr= switcher.get(argument,"Invalid Command") and then when just to call talkMe(talkMeStr)

Comment: It should looks like this.                                                                                        def switch_demo(argument):
    switcher = {"open web browser": "Opening your web browser",
        "web browser": "Opening your web browser",
        "open browser": "Opening your web browser",
        "thank you": "You are welcome",
        "thank you so much": "welcome",
        "thanks": "You are welcome"}

    talkMe(switcher.get(argument,"Invalid Command"))

Answer (score 0):

It looks you can use dictionaries.

```
d = {'Hello Google': obj1, 'open my favourite web site': obj2}
```

Comment: That's… hardly even a stub of a solution here…

Comment: can you please explain us how to use in this case? @shivank98

Comment: Instead of `obj1` you can have a list with functions as elements of it.

Comment: `def assistant(d):`

   `d = {"Hello":talkMe("Hi"),"how are you":talkMe("I am fine")}`

in while loop:

 `While True:`
 `assistant(command)`


output: 

I'm ready for next command
`Detected: hello`
`Hi`
`I am fine`
`I'm ready for next command`

Comment: You need to return obj. let me know if you need more help.